# Accessing the $_SESSION variable from pthreads

Tags: php, multithreading, session, pthreads, scoping

I'm having an issue accessing the session variable from functions called from Thread objects using the pthreads library for PHP.

When the function is called from the **main thread**, no errors occur and **everything runs fine**.

When run from a Thread object however, I get the following errors:

```
> PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: _SESSION
> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: Properties Manager
> PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function getGroupValue() on a non-object
```

The line numbers specified by the errors all point to this code block:

```
function connect_mysql_db($database, $write = false) {
    $properties = $_SESSION['Properties Manager'];

    if(!isset($database) || strlen($database)==0){
        throw new Exception("No database specified");
    }

    // Read appropriate host, port, dbname, user & pass for this database
    $host    = $properties->getGroupValue($database, DB_HOST);
    $port    = $properties->getGroupValue($database, DB_PORT);
    $db_name = $properties->getGroupValue($database, DB_NAME);
    ...Removed unnecessary code...
}
```

A little searching says that I should be able to remedy this issue by putting *session_start();* at the top of my file.
After doing this, the other errors are still printed in addition to:

```
> PHP Notice:  A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()
```

So my main question: Is there something special that I need to do when using pthreads in order to access the super-global session? Or is there something completely different at play here that I am missing?

Edit:
Yes, I have tried *global $_SESSION;* as well.

Comment: Could you just `clone()` the session array and pass that to your `Thread`?

Comment: The main issue is that this was a defined function that is not directly used by my thread. I would have to change not only this function but all the other ones that call this one.

Comment: Unless you meant pass it to the thread then make it a global variable, which is worth a try. And I'll have to try it at some point when I get back to this code.

Comment: No, I'm not advocating for a `global` solution. I don't know how you have set up your threaded code, but for me I have a `Worker` child, into which things can be injected (I'm not using a web server here but in your case, that would be the PHP/Apache entry point). A `Worker` runs permanently until it is shutdown, so from there I `stack()` a child of `Threaded`. You can pass things from one to another using setter methods. (If you are writing to the session it gets a bit more complicated, and I would just pass things back the other way and then read them in the Apache process proper).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit more research, it seems that the session variable is not thread safe and in fact locks entirely until the session is closed. I had to remove references to the session and simply pass the needed information to the function or reinitialize it.

Luckily there isn't a performance downfall of the property manager being created.